# how to create new or update if already existing product in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an action that saves new procucts like this:

```
@products = Product.new(params[:product]) 
@products.save
```

I am calling the same action for editing a product as well. But each time I edit...a new product gets created (because of above statements).

A while back I had seen some function that will only create a new record if there isn't an exising record. `create_or_update` something like that. I can not find it now.

Can anyone tell me what the method was? or give me a better approach to do this?

Comment: Sometimes this is called "upsert". That might help in your search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `find_or_create`

You can see the docs for it at http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html